# radio button are not select and deselecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have one `tableview` subclass of `UITableview` in my `Tbalview.xib`. I added three label's with one `checkBtn` at left. Here is my code:

`Tableview.h`

```
@interface TableView : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab2;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkBtn;
```

`Tableview.m`

```
@implementation TableView
@synthesize lab1 = _lab1;
@synthesize lab2 = _lab2;
@synthesize lab3 = _lab3;
@synthesize checkBtn;
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableView.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
{

    NSMutableArray *cells_Array;
    NSArray *jsonObject;

    int selectedIndex;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cells_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    selectedIndex = -1;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //NSArray *jsonObject;
    jsonObject = @[
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"199",
                       @"pointer": @"144"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"80",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"11"                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"30",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"14"


                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"100",
                       @"pointer": @"199"
                   },
                  @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"19",
                       @"pointer": @"44"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"2000",
                       @"gamer": @"500",
                       @"pointer": @"1000"
                   }
                   ];

    NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



    NSString * jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   // NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [cells_Array removeAllObjects];

    return [jsonObject count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView";
    TableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.lab1.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"gamer"];
    cell.lab2.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"partner"];
    cell.lab3.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"pointer"];

    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
    {
        [cell.checkBtn setSelected:true];
    }

    [cells_Array addObject:cell];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    for (TableView *view in cells_Array ) {
        [view.checkBtn setSelected:false];
    }
    TableView *cellView = [self.containerTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;

    [cellView.checkBtn setSelected:true];
}

@end
```

I have two images as selectBtn.png (selected) and DeselectBtn.png (deselected).

I got this code with help from `SO`. I am beginner in iOS, hence not able to find where is my mistake And also in my code  they gave some solution that worked without calling that two `.png images`

Here is that project that i got helped from SO. for this same code only . However This is not working when i tried by myself.Here is that code [Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j02yotvevxfp821/jsonTableView%203.zip?dl=0)

This above project is work well. same like i tried but that not working well for radiobutton.Here is my own project link [own projetc that not wroking](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7n73197h33ivwcv/chumaa%20tableview%202.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Check if outlet checkBtn is bound with button in TableView.xib

Comment: @bunty yes that and all correct only. please see my updated post i have added my original project for your refernece

Comment: In the attached project, you can select one option at a time which works fine. Do you want multiple selection ?

Comment: Try link the tableView with the `ViewController`. And set both it's delegate and  datasource in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @bunty  that attached project is working well.. please see my another link `own project that not working` in that only i added same code. but not able to select and deselect my radio button. And i am not asking for multiple selection

Comment: @zcui93   i added that . still not working

Comment: Please update your code in the question. Can you confirm whether `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called when you select the button, by inserting a break point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In TableView.xib, the button's selected image is not set. Choose selected state for button and choose selectBtn.png for image.

In attributes window of button, tap on State Config dropdown, choose Selected sate then below Shadow Color, there is image field; write selectBtn.png as given in snapshot. This will specify what will be the image when button is selected.

Comment: in that .xib i select the button as Deselect.png...This is what you saying or any other ..please i am beginner in ios. please explain me what to change

Comment: at first when my app run my button should in `deselectBtn.png` so when i tap my cell my button should change to `selectBtn.png`

Comment: In attributes window, tap on State Config dropdown, choose Selected sate then below Shadow Color, there is image field; write selectBtn.png as given in snapshot. This will specify what will be the image when button is selected.

Comment: i will check....is there any possible to print which cell row is selected in my console for my above code

Comment: yes that works. AND is there any possile to print and show in my console which selected cell row is i.e which cell row is in radio button selected??

Comment: Use this log NSLog(@"Select Cell Row: %d", indexPath.row); in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.